# How to prevent text selection from obstructing onMouseMove event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, preventdefault

I'm implementing a "resize handle" to change the width of my left navigation panel. It is a `div` that receives an `onMouseDown()` event, calculates the necessary widths and applies them to the right elements in the subsequent calls to `onMouseMove()`. But I'm having some problems.

1) The `article` element, to the right of the navigation panel and handle, does not activate the `onMouseUp()` if I release the mouse there. Is this because the `onMouseDown()` was activated in other element?

2) If I move the mouse fast to the right, I can't prevent the text in the `article` from being selected, even calling methods like `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`.

3) Even if there's no text in the `article`, the resizing only works if I move the mouse very slowly. If the mouse moves fast over the `article` element, the resize stops, unless I release the mouse button - in this case the resize goes smoothly (suggesting it was the text-selecting that was stopping the resize, even with no text at all). But if I release the mouse button, the resize should stop (see point 1).

I've seen some solutions using CSS `user-select: none`, but this would prevent any text from being selected inside `article`, which is obviously an overkill.

So, how can I make the resizing smooth, without selecting any text, when I move the mouse over any element in my document? (After pressing the button in the right `div`, of course.)

That's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>CSS Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Header</header>
<main>
    <nav id='nav'>
        <div class='navcont' onmousemove='handMm(event)' onmouseup='handMu(event)'>
            <p>nav 1</p>
            <p>nav 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class='handle' onmousedown='handMd(event)' onmousemove='handMm(event)' onmouseup='handMu(event)'>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <article id='article' onmousemove='handMm(event)' onmouseup='handMu(event)'>
    </article>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

That's my CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
header {
    text-align:center;
}
main {
    flex:1;
    display:flex;
    min-height:0;
}
article {
    background:#CCC;
    width:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:10px;
    flex-grow:1;
}
nav {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;
}
.navcont {
    background:#8C8;
    width:auto;
    flex-grow:1;
}
.handle {
    background:#333;
    right:0px;
    width:30px;
    cursor:col-resize;
}
footer {
    text-align:center;
}
```

That's my Javascript:

```
var mx,px,moving=false;
function handMd(e) {
    mx = e.pageX;
    px = document.getElementById('nav').clientWidth;
    moving = true;
}
function handMm(e) {
    if (moving) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = false;
        var diff = e.pageX - mx;
        document.getElementById('nav').style.width = (px + diff)+'px';
        document.getElementById('article').style.width = (window.innerWidth-px-diff)+'px';
    }
}
function handMu(e) {
    moving = false;
}
```

And here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/45h7vq7u/

Another example, including Ryan Tsui's answer: https://jsfiddle.net/v1cmk2f6/1/ (the text-selection is gone, but the div still won't move smoothly, but only when moving fast to the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing how this was solved [somewhere else](https://codepen.io/lingtalfi/pen/zoNeJp), I came to the following changes.

HTML - only one event handler needed:

```
...
<main>
    <nav id='nav'>
        <div class='navcont'>
            <p>nav 1</p>
            <p>nav 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class='handle' onmousedown='handMd(event)'>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <article id='article'>
    </article>
</main>
...
```

Javascript - attach and detach the onmousemove event handler is way better than calling onmousemove every time the mouse moves (to only then test if the mouse button has been pressed). Also, the event is now attached to the document, not to each div on screen:

```
var mx,px,minW = 200;
function handMd(e) {
    mx = e.pageX;
    px = document.getElementById('nav').clientWidth;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove',handMm);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup',handMu);
    document.getElementById('article').classList.toggle('moving',true);
    document.getElementById('nav').classList.toggle('moving',true);
}
function handMm(e) {
    var diff = e.pageX - mx;
    if (px+diff >= minW && window.innerWidth-px-diff >= minW) {
        document.getElementById('nav').style.width = (px+diff)+'px';
        document.getElementById('article').style.width = (window.innerWidth-px-diff)+'px';
    }
}
function handMu(e) {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove',handMm);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup',handMu);
    document.getElementById('article').classList.toggle('moving',false);
    document.getElementById('nav').classList.toggle('moving',false);
}
```

CSS - thanks to Ryan Tsui's answer, I eliminated the unwanted text selection while resizing:

```
.moving {
    user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch the events of `start moving` and `finish moving` with your preferred method (`onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` are fine). Add a CSS class to specify the moving state when the action starts. Remove the CSS class when the action finishes.

In your case, you may try the followings:

Add a new CSS class:

```
.moving {
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Extend your `handMd()` and `handMu()` functions:

```
function handMd(e) {
    mx = e.pageX;
    px = document.getElementById('nav').clientWidth;
    moving = true;
    document.getElementById('article').classList.toggle('moving', true);  // Add this line. 'article' is the id of the element where you don't want the selection to occur.
}
function handMu(e) {
    moving = false;
    document.getElementById('article').classList.toggle('moving', false);  // Add this line. 'article' is the id of the element where you don't want the selection to occur.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it stopped selecting the text inside 'article'. Anyway, the bar is not yet moving as smoothly as it should. Also, I made a few editions (waiting to be peer reviewed): user-select is not valid, so I changed it for the browser specific variants (like -webkit-...), and added true and false to the toggle functions.

Comment: Cool. Almost forget about the browser specific variants. Seldom write those manually as those are mostly done with autoprefixer / postcss nowadays. Haha. Anyway, it's still better to always include the basic `user-select` in the CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to stop the selection but I can tell you for some help that the event triggered when something is selected is `onselect`.

Comment: Thank you. But I think this goes better as a comment.

Comment: @Rodringo I'm really sorry for that but I don't have a privilege to do so. Pardon me!

Comment: Ok, no need to excuse yourself. You're welcome! And thanks again for your help.